# Best Practice for Services

Tags: 2013, web-services

I'm looking into where I should put my services what server (web or app) and where it would be best to have dedicated servers for them.
I have a basic topology at the moment with 2 web apps 2 apps which I have been intended to be highly available.

Where is best to put the following services (web or app)
Business data connectivity
Managed Metadata
Incoming email
subscription setting 
Secure store
Visio

As well as that are there any services apart from search that would be best to have a dedicated server for? Such as Distributed Cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft introduced the [Streamlined Topology](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37000) concept in SharePoint 2013. It's main goal is to put all low-load services with high impact on your siteperformance to your front-end servers (e.g. ManagedMetaData Service). High-Load Services will be deployed on different servers (Search).

The "full Version" of a streamlined topology has a total of 5 server roles:

- Front-End
- Batch-Processing
- Distributed Cache
- Specialized Workloads
- SQL-Database

This topology is oversized for most mid-range farms. I often see and install a topology with:

- Front-End (all Services including Distributed Cache - except Search)
- Batch-Processing (Search)
- SQL-Database (all Databases)

Ifyou want to be highly-available on application-level, you need two of each. So a total of 6 servers would be required. If you want to use OfficeWebApps (recommended) you need another Server.

Some more articles to read:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219591.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx

https://nikpatel.net/2013/03/20/new-best-practices-for-sharepoint-2013-farm-design-streamlined-topology/